# How to fit a function without fitting the feature of interest using scipy.optimize?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am performing a curve fit using scipy.optimize. I only want to fit the first part and last part of the spectrum. The middle part of the spectrum has all the interesting features, so I obviously do not want to fit that region. How could you do that?

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np 
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl

def func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

xdata = np.linspace(0, 4, 50)
y = func(xdata, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5)
np.random.seed(1729)
y_noise = 0.2 * np.random.normal(size=xdata.size)
ydata = y + y_noise
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')
```

[image]

The feature of interest is between 2 and 2.5, so I don't want to do a curve fit in that range. I just want to do a curve fit before 2 and after 2.5. How could I do that using scipy.optimize? Because the issue I get is that it performs the fit throughout the entire spectrum. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your data, and on what you have already tried by including a minimal working example?

Comment: My guess is that you would remove the data you do not want to fit.

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task is ( assuming I understand the question correctly and as James Phillips pointed out in his comment) quite simple. There are several ways to achieve it, though. Here is one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def decay( x, a, b, c ):
    return a + b * np.exp( - c * x )

xList = np.linspace( 0, 5, 121 )
yList = np.fromiter( ( .6 * np.exp( -( x - 2.25 )**2 / .05 ) + decay( x, .3, 1, .6) + .05 * np.random.normal() for x in xList ), np.float )

takeList = np.concatenate( np.argwhere( np.logical_or(xList < 2., xList > 2.5) ) )
featureList = np.concatenate( np.argwhere( np.logical_and(xList >= 2., xList <= 2.5) ) )

xSubList = xList[ takeList ]
ySubList = yList[ takeList ]
xFtList = xList[ featureList ]
yFtList = yList[ featureList ]

myFit, _ = curve_fit( decay,  xSubList, ySubList )

fitList = np.fromiter( ( decay( x, *myFit) for x in xList ), np.float )
cleanY = np.fromiter( ( y - decay( x, *myFit) for x,y in zip( xList, yList ) ), np.float )

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( xList, yList )
ax.plot( xSubList, ySubList - .1, '--' ) ## -0.1 offset for visibility
ax.plot( xFtList, yFtList + .1, ':' ) ## +0.1 offset for visibility
ax.plot( xList, fitList, '-.' )
ax.plot( xList, cleanY ) ## feature without background
plt.show()
```

[image: Getting the feature without background]